# Why WCF (in this particular scenario)?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, asmx, ashx

I need a list of websites (in the form of JSON) from my server to be consumed by the client and displayed using jQuery.

I've added an ashx file and with minimal fuss I've got it wokring in 3 or 4 minutes.

I've been advised, however, that I should steer clear of ashx/asmx in favour of opting for WCF instead. Considering I don't need this application to necessarily scale, and I won't expect any other app/platform to want to consume such a service - is this not bad advice?

From my experience, configuring WCF endpoints and troubleshooting config/IIS problems as a result of implementing WCF services is not something I've had a problem with at all with asp .net handlers/services.

Is there a need here for me to move to WCF?

Answer (score 1):

*If* your solution is working to your requirements, there is no need to move to WCF.

If you start a bigger project in the future, you may want to use WCF because asmx is outdated and dying though.

Comment: Thanks, +1. In what way could my requirements change to make my current solution unfeasible?